# Get data from webstie

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webclient

I'm working at a little WindowsPhone project where I want to get data from a website, for example IMDb.

So I've download the html from an IMDb-page with

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webclient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2294449/"));
    }

    void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
        string html = e.Result;
    }
```

So far it works.

Now I want to search in this html for de title of the movie. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use regular expressions to parse the HTML manually, however due to the irregularity of HTML code, you would be better of (and would likely get less errors!) using a HTML parsing library such as HTML Agility Pack.

Answer (score 0):

Get the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Here's some code to get you started (requires error checking)

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument(); 
string htmlString = "<html>blabla</html>";
document.LoadHtml(htmlString);
HtmlNodeCollection collection = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
foreach (HtmlNode link in collection)
{
     string target = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
}
```